# Ionic 2 : Get device's informations

Tags: android, angular, typescript, ionic2, device

I try to get the device's information in a component but I don't know how to do that. I tried this :

```
console.log(Device.device.model);
```

But it return "undifined".

How can I get this information ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you install plugin?

```
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-device


import { Device } from 'ionic-native';


console.log('Device: ' + Device);
```

Read more on http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/device/

Comment: Sure, the plugin is install. The import is done and I tried this code. But same problem ...